# Using the alternatives for copyrighted zero derivation words (e.g. "LEGO", "Xerox"

Tags: terminology, names, synonymy

We have seen how copyright infringement goes into zero derivation English words such as `a Xerox clone` or `He was Googling it` or even `A lego like construction`. (e.g. http://agile.dzone.com/articles/real-lessons-lego-software)

To avoid copyright lawsuit, **is there a list of words alternative word/phrase that one can use for such zero derivation words that comes with arcane copyright laws?**

What would be a good alternative for phrases such as:

- Lego like construction
- a Xerox clone
- He googled long and hard to find her

Comment: This is not linguistics. It's not even copyright. It's about trademark, which is part of law. It vaguely touches on lexicography at best.

Comment: The normative usage of terms (especially to avoid law infringements) has nothing to do with linguistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copyright isn't relevant to this. If any law is involved it will be *trademark* law. But some genericised trademarks are no longer enforceable.
2. Specific answers for your examples are:

   1. snapable bricks (perhaps. I'm not certain if there is a common generic name for Lego-like toys)
   2. photocopier. In Australia we never say anything other than photocopier.
   3. searched the internet for ...
3. Here is a list, though it is incomplete of course: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks
4. Why are you asking about zero derivations? Only Googled is derived - Lego and Xerox aren't, at least not in the examples you gave.